# Finding an $\varepsilon$-net for $A$ with $A = B_{1}(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a question over an example that I've been given over the concept of $\epsilon$-net

> Let $A = B_{1}(0)\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$. We want to find an $\varepsilon$-net for $A$. To this end, we place points $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots ,p_n\}\subset A$ s. t. $d(p_{i},p_{j}) < \varepsilon$ for $i \ne j$.
>
> We have 
>   \begin{align*}
> \bigcup_{j=1}^{N} B_{\Large \epsilon / \small 2}(p_{j}) \subset B_{1+ \Large \varepsilon / \small 2} (0)
> \end{align*}
>
> and $B_{\Large \varepsilon / \small 2 }(p_{j})$ are disjoint, so
>
> $vol\bigr(\bigcup_{j=1}^{N} B_{\Large \varepsilon / \small 2} (p_{j})) = N \cdot vol(B_{\Large \varepsilon / \small 2} (p_{j})) = N \cdot vol(B_{\Large \varepsilon / \small 2}(0))$
>
> $= N \cdot(\frac{\varepsilon}{2})^{k} \cdot vol(B_{1}(0)) \le vol(B_{1 + \Large \varepsilon / \small 2}(0)) = \biggl(1+ \frac{ \Large \varepsilon}{2} \biggr)$
>
> Thus,
>
> $N \le \dfrac{\biggl(1+ \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2} \biggr)^{k}}{\biggl(\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\biggr)^{k}} = \biggl(1 + \dfrac{2}{\varepsilon} \biggr)$
>
> We know there is $N$ such that $N \le \biggl(1 + \dfrac{2}{\varepsilon}\biggr)^{k} < N+1$, so the procedure stops and we cannot place $p_{j}$ any more s.t.$d(p_{j},p_{k}) \ge\varepsilon$ with $p_{k} \le N$.

I'm kind of confused about the last part. Can someone further explain why the procedure stops? Also, should the last sentence instead say that we cannot place $p_{j}$ any more such that $d(p_{j},p_{i})< \varepsilon$ with $p_{j} \le N$? I'm also not sure what $p_{j} \le N$ means.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, that example is woefully complicated.

Consider the sets ${\cal C}_0 = \{[0,1)^k+\{x\} | x \in \mathbb{Z}^k \}$, that is, the integer translates of the 'half open cubes' $[0,1)^k$.

Now scale these to get the collections ${\cal C}_n = \{ {1 \over 2^n} C | C \in {\cal C}_0 \}$.

We can tag any element of this collection with the 'lower left' point (for example,
the point $(0,0,...)$ is the 'tag' associated with the element $[0,1)^k \in {\cal C}_0$).

If we fix $n$ we see that any $x \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ is contained in exactly one of the elements $C_x \in {\cal C}_n$ and that $\|x-c\| \le \sqrt{n \over 2} { 1 \over 2^n}$ for
all $c \in C_x$.

Now pick $\epsilon>0$ and choose $n$ such that $\sqrt{n \over 2} { 1 \over 2^n} < \epsilon$. Let ${\cal A} = \{ C \in  {\cal C}_n | C \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$, and note that ${\cal A}$ is finite. To get our $\epsilon$-net, for each $C \in {\cal A}$, pick any $x_C \in A \cap C$, and then let $N= \{x_C\}_{C \in A}$. Then $N$ is an $\epsilon$-net
for $A$.